# Hibernate one to many: Should the entity contain the foreign key or the whole object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to learn the hibernate api. I am having a hard time with relationships and how they should be employed.

Consider the following example.
We have two tables, Owners and Cars. We assume that a car can only be owned by one,therefore the cars have a many to one relationship with the owners.

Now a regular SQL database would look like this.

```
|------------|                         |------------|
|   Owner    | 1 ------------------- N |    Car     |
|------------|                         |------------|
|    id      |                         |     id     |
|    name    |                         |    model   |
|------------|                         |   car_id   |
                                       |------------|
```

Now the hard part comes when I try to write the entities using Anotations.

Especially the Car entity.

My questions are two:

1.Should the car class entity have a field of long called carId or should it be an Owner owner field?

2.Also should i include the one to many and the many to one relationship in both entities or only one is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suppose that `Car` should rather have an `owner_id` instead of a `car_id`.

Reason: I think you want to express the foreign key with it, as `Car` already has `id` as primary key. Now, I expect the foreign key to be named after the foreign entity, which is `Owner`.

Comment: Integer IDs are a database hack to speed up queries and not a first-class part of the object model. Relationships in the object model are between object types, not their artificial IDs, as shown in the answers here. Entity `equals` and related methods (`hashCode`, etc.) should be written in terms of the object's key values, or in database terms, the _natural key_.

Answer (score 3):

You should have bidirectional relationship each other like:

```
/*Many to one relationship with owner in class Car*/
public class Car {
  @Id 
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne 
  private Owner owner;

}

/*One to many relationship with car in class Owner*/

public class Owner {
  @Id 
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner") 
  private List<Car> cars;
}
```

Comment: Please explain a little more; Your answer is mostly code

Comment: Note, how the `mappedBy` attribute informs JPA/Hibernate, that `Owner.cars` is the counterpart of `Car.owner`, and that the `cars` collection might be built up by collecting all the `Car` instances with the right owner.

Answer (score 0):

so you should use Owner as type and if you want to access the cars of an owner and the owner of the car, you have to set the relationship in both classes.

```
public class Car {
  @Id private int id;
  @ManyToOne private Owner owner;
  private String model;
  /** getters and setters */

}


public class Owner {
  @Id private int id;
  private String name;
  @OneToMany private List<Car> cars;

  /** getters and setters */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In provided relationship master entity is Owner. And as example from real life Owner can have multiple cars. In this case each car should have reference to the owner (owner_id) or you can use relational table. You can specify unidirectional mapping or bi-directional mapping.

Example of unidirectional:

```
public class Owner {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

Example of bi-directional:

```
public class Owner {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Car> cars;
}

public class Car {
    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;
}
```